# I am facing an error while deploying child lwc component in vscode as No MODULE named markup://c:modal found : [markup://c:testingreusableModal]

Tags: javascript, deployment-error

**HTML file**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Modal Component Testing">
        <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
            <lightning-button variant="brand" label="open" onclick={openHandler}></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button variant="brand" label="open Second" onclick={openSecondHandler}></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
    <template if:true={isOpen}>
        <c-modal onclose={closeHandler}>
            <h1 slot="title">Modal header</h1>
            <p>Sit nulla est ex deserunt exercitation anim occaecat. Nostrud ullamco deserunt aute id consequat veniam incididunt duis in sint irure nisi. Mollit officia cillum Lorem ullamco minim nostrud elit officia tempor esse quis.
                Cillum sunt ad dolore quis aute consequat ipsum magna exercitation reprehenderit magna. </p>
            <div slot="footer">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick={closeHandler}>Cancel</button>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand">Save</button>
            </div>
        </c-modal>
    </template>

    <template if:true={isOpenSecond}>
        <c-modal onclose={secondCloseHandler}>
            <h1 slot="title">Second Modal header</h1>
            <p>Hello Everyone This is the second modal </p>
            
        </c-modal>
    </template>
</template>
```

**js file**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class testingreusableModal extends LightningElement {
    isOpen = false
    isOpenSecond = false
    openHandler(){
        console.log("Clicked!!")
        this.isOpen = true
    }
    openSecondHandler(){
        this.isOpenSecond = true
    }
    closeHandler(){
        this.isOpen = false
    }
    secondCloseHandler(){
        this.isOpenSecond = false
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure, your org has `modal` lwc component deployed

Comment: I sometimes face a similar error when I try to deploy it from my component's JS file. If you go to xml file and right click then deploy from there it works for me.